# What does "const class" mean?

Tags: c++, class, constants

After some find and replace refactoring I ended up with this gem:

```
const class A
{
};
```

What does "const class" mean? It seems to compile ok.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> What does "const class" mean? It seems to compile ok.

Not for me it doesn't. I think your compiler's just being polite and ignoring it.

**Edit:** Yep, VC++ silently ignores the const, GCC complains.

Comment: I'm going to say it looks like an edge case that VC++ is getting wrong

Comment: Looks like; the 'const' doesn't affect anything that I can find.

Comment: VC++ digests really a lot of ill-formed code (I'm using 2013 now). It seems they tested it just for happy paths.

Answer (score 54):

The `const` is meaningless in that example, and your compiler should give you an error, but if you use it to declare variables of that class between the closing `}` and the `;`, then that defines those instances as `const`, e.g.:

```
const class A
{
public:
    int x, y;
}  anInstance = {3, 4};

// The above is equivalent to:
const A anInstance = {3, 4};
```

Comment: I can't find a justification to make this an error. Compilers may emit warnings at will, but only the standard determines what counts as an error.

Comment: Because you're declaring something as const that isn't. This is something that is never what you want to do, and so should be an error. The standard should determine what is correct; defining every wrong thing would be too much work.

Comment: I think that the term used in the standard is "illformed".  The standard doesn't say what isn't allowed, only what is.  This isn't valid C++ syntax, therefore isn't allowed.

Comment: It's an error because the storage class specifiers are only applicable if you have a declarator and in this example there is no declarator.

Comment: 7.1.5.1/1: "There are two cv-qualifiers, const and volatile. If a cv-qualifier appears in a decl-specifier-seq, the init-declarator-list of the declaration shall not be empty."

Answer (score 22):

If you had this:

```
const class A
{
} a;
```

Then it would clearly mean that 'a' is const. Otherwise, I think that it is likely invalid c++.

Answer (score 9):

It's meaningless unless you declare an instance of the class afterward, such as this example:

```
const // It is a const object...
class nullptr_t 
{
  public:
    template<class T>
      operator T*() const // convertible to any type of null non-member pointer...
    { return 0; }

    template<class C, class T>
    operator T C::*() const   // or any type of null member pointer...
    { return 0; }

  private:
    void operator&() const;  // Can't take address of nullptr

} nullptr = {};
```

An interim `nullptr` implementation if you're waiting for C++0x.

Answer (score 1):

Try compiling it with GCC, it will give you below error:
`error: qualifiers can only be specified for objects and functions.`

As you can see from the error that only objects(variables, pointers, class objects etc.) and functions can be constant. So try making the object as constant, then it should compile fine.
     `const class A {};`
    `const A a ;`