# const template template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, eigen3, template-templates

I'm trying to design the following (very simplified) class:

```
template<int Dim, template<int,int> class Matrix>
class MatrixWrapperBase
{
    using InternalType Matrix<Dim,Dim>;
    InternalType member_;
public:
    // Provide additional functionalities
};
```

where `Matrix` is a generic template class implementing common matrix functionalities; in my specific case it is just a typedef of the `Eigen::Matrix` class:

```
template<int R, int C>
using MyMatrix = Eigen::Matrix<double,R,C>;
```

Now, I would like to provide both the non-`const` and the `const InternalType` version of this class (iterators-inspired) using aliases like:

```
template<int Dim>
using MatrixWrapper = MatrixWrapperBase<Dim,MyMatrix>;

template<int Dim>
using ConstMatrixWrapper = MatrixWrapperBase<Dim,const MyMatrix>;   // ERROR
```

I'm perfectly aware of the reasons why the latter does not compile (they are well explained in this answer, for instance [template template class with const template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998539/template-template-class-with-const-template-parameter)), so I tried to use another template-template argument alias for the `const` case:

```
template<int R, int C>
using MyConstMatrix = Eigen::Matrix<const double, R, C>;
...
template<int Dim>
using ConstMatrixWrapper = MatrixWrapperBase<Dim,MyConstMatrix>;
```

Unfortunately, Eigen refuse to compile when I try to instance a `ConstMatrixWrapper` object (or a `MyConstMatrix` object as well) because of the following error:

```
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:474:27: error: ‘static Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::MapType Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::Map(Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::Scalar*) [with Derived = Eigen::Matrix<const double, 2, 2>; Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::MapType = Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<const double, 2, 2>, 0, Eigen::Stride<0, 0> >; Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::Scalar = const double]’ cannot be overloaded
     static inline MapType Map(Scalar* data)
                       ^
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:472:32: error: with ‘static Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::ConstMapType Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::Map(const Scalar*) [with Derived = Eigen::Matrix<const double, 2, 2>; Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::ConstMapType = const Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Matrix<const double, 2, 2>, 0, Eigen::Stride<0, 0> >; Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::Scalar = const double]’
     static inline ConstMapType Map(const Scalar* data)
```

I found a workaround by adding a `bool` template argument to the `MatrixWrapperBase` class to discriminate between the `const` and the non-`const` case in such a way:

```
template<bool Constness, int Dim, template<int,int> class Matrix>
class MatrixWrapperBase
{
    using InternalType = std::conditional_t<Constness, const Matrix<Dim,Dim>, Matrix<Dim,Dim>>;
    ...
};

template<int Dim>
using MatrixWrapper = MatrixWrapperBase<false,Dim,MyMatrix>;

template<int Dim>
using ConstMatrixWrapper = MatrixWrapperBase<true,Dim,MyMatrix>;
```

but I would like to avoid such a design, if possible.

Can anyone give me a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about `template <typename> class MatrixWrapperBase;` and then `MatrixWrapperBase</*const*/ MyMatrix<42, 42>>` ?

Comment: You can still add traits to retrieve `Dimension` from given Matrix or create Matrix with other dimensions.

Comment: @Jarod42 I thought about using traits, but in this case they seem to me an unnecessary complication in `MatrixWrapper` object definition. I would prefer specifying just the `Dimension` when creating a new `MatrixWrapper` object.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

```
template <typename M> struct MatrixWrapperHelper;

template<int D1, int D2, template<int,int> class Matrix>
struct MatrixWrapperHelper<Matrix<Dim1, Dim2>>
{
    template <int NewDim1, int NewDim2>
    using ResizedType = Matrix<NewDim1, NewDim2>;

    static constexpr int Dim1 = D1;
    static constexpr int Dim2 = D2;
};


template <typename M> class MatrixWrapperBase
{
    using MatrxType = std::decay_t<M>;
    // MatrixWrapperHelper<MatrxType>::Dim1
    // typename MatrixWrapperHelper<MatrxType>::template Resized<42, 42>

    using InternalType = M;
    M member_;
public:
    // Provide additional functionalities
};
```

And finally:

```
template<int Dim>
using MatrixWrapper = MatrixWrapperBase<MyMatrix<Dim, Dim>>;

template<int Dim>
using ConstMatrixWrapper = MatrixWrapperBase<const MyMatrix<Dim, Dim>>;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I found a workaround by adding a bool template argument to the MatrixWrapperBase class to discriminate between the const and the non-const case in such a way [...] but I would like to avoid such a design, if possible.

What's wrong with an additional `bool` template argument?

Anyway, you can obtain something similar using partial template specialization defaulting `bool` template values.

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <type_traits>

template <int, int>
struct Mtx
 { };

template <typename T, bool = false, bool = std::is_const<T>::value>
struct MatrixWrapperBase 
 { };

template <int Dim, template <int,int> class Matrix, bool C>
struct MatrixWrapperBase<Matrix<Dim, Dim>, C, false>
 {
   using InternalType = typename std::conditional<C,
            Matrix<Dim, Dim> const, Matrix<Dim, Dim>>::type;
 };

template <typename T>
struct MatrixWrapperBase<T, false, true>
   : public MatrixWrapperBase<typename std::remove_const<T>::type,
                              true, false>
 { };

int main()
 {
   MatrixWrapperBase<Mtx<1, 1>>        mwb;
   MatrixWrapperBase<Mtx<1, 1> const>  cmwb;

   static_assert( std::is_same<typename decltype(mwb)::InternalType,
                               Mtx<1, 1>>{}, "!");
   static_assert( std::is_same<typename decltype(cmwb)::InternalType,
                               Mtx<1, 1> const> {}, "!");

 }
```

Comment: @Jarod42 - I've tried with only a `bool` parameter but without success; anyway is the flag that say us if the original type `T` (the first template parameter) was or wasn't `const`. I mean: if is directly activated the first partial specialization (if `T` isn't `const`), it is `false`, as default value. If the type `T` is `const`, is activated the second specialization that inherit from the first but with a `true` for the first `bool` parameter.

Comment: Oh, I think I got that usage, indirection level... I think that introducing a helper class is easier to read: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40d8ab7f6f989aa6)