# c++ error: qualifiers can only be specified

Tags: c++

I am not completely sure why this is generating that error:

```
const class MyString {
public:
MyString() { _len = 0; _str = NULL; }
MyString(const char* in);
MyString(const MyString&);
~MyString();

int set(const char*);
int set(const MyString&);

int setLength(int len) { _len = len; return 0; }
int getLength() { return _len; }

char * getStr() { return _str; }
int getStr(char* out) const;

MyString operator+(const MyString & in);
MyString operator+(const char* in);
MyString operator+(const char in) {const char* temp = &in; return *this + temp; }

MyString operator=(const MyString & in)
    { this->set(in); return *this; }
MyString operator=(const char* in)
    { if(in) this->set(in); return *this; }
MyString operator=(const char in) {const char* temp = &in; return *this = temp; }

MyString operator+=(const MyString & in)
    { this->set(*this + in); return *this; }
MyString operator+=(const char* in)
    { if(in) this->set(*this + in); return *this; }
MyString operator+=(const char in) { return (*this + in); }

int operator==(const MyString& in);
int operator!=(const MyString& in);
int operator==(const char* in);
int operator!=(const char* in);

friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const MyString & in)
    { os << in._str; return os; }

protected:
char * _str;
int _len;
};
```

The error is being generated at the last line.  The only code before that definition are 'standard' #includes and using namespace std.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message you posted is not complete, but nevermind that.

Long story short: remove the `const` qualifier at the very top of your class declaration, the one just before the `class` keyword. You can only add cv-qualifiers (`const / volatile`) either on variables or methods.

Comment: Thank you much.  Any idea why I got the error when using g++ but not Visual Studio?

Comment: @user1404053 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206998/what-does-const-class-mean

Comment: @Andrei: Thanks for that link, the quote from the standard in the comments to [@AdamRosenfield's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/207007/2070725) is particularly informative.