# "Missing type specifier - int assumed" cannot be solved by adding "return 0" to the main function

Tags: c++

I am trying to figure out how the C++ key word "this" works. I followed the codes below, but it does not pass and show the error of `"C4430: Missing type specifier, int assumed"`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void PrintEntity(const Entity& e);

class Entity
{
public:
    int x, y;

    Entity(int x, int y)
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;

        PrintEntity(*this);
    }
};

void PrintEntity(const Entity& e)
{
    std::cout << "Entity" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I reviewed other similar questions, the solutions include adding "return 0" to the Main function or circular dependency. But I don't think these solutions apply for me. Please help me solve it, thanks!

Comment: You have to declare `class Entity;` before using it.

Comment: @M.M I have added the error code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to declare `PrintEntity`'s interface before the type of its one parameter is even declared, `Entity`.

You have to declare `Entity` first (without defining it, as its definition does use `PrintEntity`), before you use it in `PrintEntity`'s declaration. You can do this by adding the line `class Entity;` before `PrintEntity`'s declaration.

Once they're both declared, then the definitions are ok.

**Important**

As suggested in the comments, one more way to have the code compile/work, is to use a so called [elaborated type specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier). With reference to the specific example, it is enough to change

```
void PrintEntity(const Entity& e);
```

to

```
void PrintEntity(const class Entity& e);
```

Comment: But how should I modify it? In this example, I have to call the PrintEntity method within the constructor but the PrintEntity method requires the Entity as its parameter.

Comment: Yes, or declare the function as `void PrintEntity(const class Entity& e);`.

Comment: You only **declare** the class. Just put the line `class Entity;` before `void PrintEntity(const Entity& e);` without modifying anything else.

Comment: Doing that with all your main classes has value anyway, humans like a nice overview as much as the compiler.

Comment: Thanks, they all pass well. But the declaration "void PrintEntity(const class Entity& e);" is a little bit wired for me.

Comment: Why is that? It's so clear, isn't it? I agree with @jthill.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Does `const class Entity` mean declaring the `class Entity` within the declaration of the `PrintEntity` (syntax combined)? Or does it have other more general uses? I could not find detailed explanation for this syntax.

Comment: @QiangYao, to be honest I had not got that you were referring to what @FredLarson suggested. However I did not know about that syntax. I've checked it works, so my deduction is that it is sort of an "in-place" declaration. Unfortunately I've not been able to find a documentation for this, at the moment. Not even [the most voted question on `[c++] const class`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206998/what-does-const-class-mean) mentions this syntax.

Comment: @FredLarson, can you give a documentation reference for the syntax that you suggested?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis: It's a form of [elaborated type specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier).

Comment: Thank you, @FredLarson, I've added this suggestion of yours to the answer, in order to give it more visibility.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Learned a lot from these open and exploratory comments!

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind that you don't have to define everything in the class all at once. Another option is to defer the definition of the constructor to after the definition of `PrintEntity`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Entity
{
public:
    int x, y;

    Entity(int x, int y);
};

void PrintEntity(const Entity& e)
{
    std::cout << "Entity" << std::endl;
}

Entity::Entity(int x, int y)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;

    PrintEntity(*this);
}
```

In this case you can get rid of the declaration of `PrintEntity` before the definition of the `Entity` class because you don't need it yet.